# XCode7.1 stop immediately after build success

Tags: xcode7

XCode7.1 build success but it stopped immediately.It did not show any error message.any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance

Comment: How can we debug ? We're not prophet . Yet , you can try to reboot the device (both Mac and phone) first .

Comment: Have you look at Console

Comment: i did restart mac..still having same issue

Comment: yes..no message in console..